# SUSE SLES Licensing in GCP after migration from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, licensing, sles

I migrated an SLES image from AWS to GCP following this [Guide](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.11/how-to/migrate-aws-to-gcp/overview#prepare_your_linux_vms).
Recently I realized that the repositories aren't working due to the fact that the machine is not properly registered to SMT.

Since I don't have a respective license because source image is licensed to AWS  in a [Pay As You Go](https://www.suse.com/c/sles-sap-gce/) mode it means I am unable to have registered SLES in GCP after a successful migration.

So based on the [types of licensing models available in GCP](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/compute/compute-engine-licensing-explained), I want to achieve OPTION 2: Bring your own image (SLES) with GCP provided licenses, with an image/instance already migrated to GCP from AWS. Anyone has any idea on how to achieve this solution?

This is the same issue as reported in https://groups.google.com/g/google-cloud-dev/c/uWWXaHuv3h8

Comment: What version of RHEL are you using ? To be able to use GCP provided license it has to be [6/7 or 11/12](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.11/how-to/prepare-vms-servers/using-premium-os-licenses#prerequisites).

Comment: Actually it's suse SLES server not RHEL, i wanted  to know if it would be possible to apply that option 2 to that type of image and how, if the machine is already inside our environment.

Comment: My bad - don't know why I was thinking about RHEL where you clearly said otherwise. Am I correct to assume that you want to keep your SLES instance (and don't have to undergo another migration) and additionally want it to have GCP's license ? Whats the `gcloud compute instances describe your_sles_vm_name --zone=your_vm_zone | grep license` output ?

Comment: Here, the results of that query: 

`licenses:
- https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/velospublic/global/licenses/veloslicense
  - key: license_type`

Answer (score 0):

What you're experiencing is expected behavior since **there's no way to migrate pay-as-you-go AWS licence to GCP** at this moment. The only guaranteed way is to move only your data to GCP and use similar licence.

However you can try fallowing solution. **But that would mean cloning your VM's disk and attaching additional licence to it**.

First yuu need to stop your SLES VM.
Next you create a new image with the contentes of your VM's system disk and attach a proper license:

```
gcloud compute images create your_new_sles_image_name \
--source-disk=your_current_sles_disk_name \
--source-disk-zone=your_zone_here \
--licenses="https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/suse-cloud/global/licenses/sles-12"`
```

I assume you're using SLES 12 but if it's version 15 just replace the name of the license in the `gcloud` command.

Now you can [create a new disk out of this image](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/create) and [attach it to existing SLES VM](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/attach-disk) (but first detach the old one) or go straight to creating new VM (if that's not an issue) and use this image as a template for a system disk.

> The key here is the URI for the license. All the SUSE licenses for SLES are in the suse-cloud project and licenses for SLES For SAP are in the suse-sap-cloud project. The license names for SLES are sles-12 and sles-15 when SUSE Linux Enterprise Server version 15 is released later this year. For SLES For SAP the names are sles-sap-12 and sles-sap-15 when SLES 15 For SAP gets released.
>
> With this the URI for SLES 15 For SAP would be
>
> `https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/suse-sap-cloud/global/licenses/sles-sap-15`

Next there's some actual configuration to do with your SLES - have a look at this page (where I got the initial idea from) and try going through the steps mentioned in the [***Option 2: More prep less fiddling once uploaded***](https://www.suse.com/c/create-sles-demand-images-gce/).

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing that information, i had tried that method before but nonetheless i give it another go, and as for the steps you mentioned it created an image successfully i was able to create a disk with that image. 
i attach it to an existing SLES VM, but the problems start to arise once i start to perform the steps mentioned in the tutorial  [Option 2: More prep less fiddling once uploaded.](https://www.suse.com/c/create-sles-demand-images-gce/)

Comment: Here it when i performed the pint command it doesn't show as expected all the servers are smt only, and in some cases it gives the flag `"regionserver-sles"` or `"regionserver-sap"` and not as expected `smt-sles` or `smt-sap`, and currently for my region europe-west3 there are no region servers are not available, only smt.
This is the format: 
 ` <server ip="130.211.88.88" name="" region="europe-west1" type="regionserver-sles"/>`
 and this:
  `<server ip="35.198.118.99" name="smt-gce.susecloud.net" region="europe-west3" type="smt"/>`

Comment: But i decided to try again with both ip's and only the second one with name region was working, so i used that one, and i get blocked in the step to register my system because in my case it gives the following message:
Code: `SUSEConnect –url https://smt-gce.susecloud.net –instance-data instance_md.xml`
Result:`Updating system details on https://smt-ec2.susecloud.net...
SUSEConnect error: SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known`
It should register to smt-gce not smt-ec2.. i changed the /etc/hosts according to the steps, i don't know why this is happening do you have suggestion?

Comment: Is it possible for you to just create a fresh SLES VM from GCP provided image and move your date & services there ?